# What part of speech is 'inspired' here?

Tags: adjectives, parts-of-speech, past-participles

I'm not sure if 'inspired' here is a verb in past participle or an adjective.

> Director George Lucas was inspired to create the Wookiee
> character Chewbacca—a “gentle, hairy, non-English-speaking
> co-pilot”—after seeing his wife’s dog sitting in the
> passenger seat of his car.

Comment: It could be either, but it's probly a past participle in a passive construction. However, *_after being seen his wife's dog_ is ungrammatical.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is 'stapled' verb or adjective in 'the blue page is stapled to the red page?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159334/verb-or-adjective-in-the-blue-page-is-stapled-to-the-red-page) or  [Is "rumored" a verb or an adjective (a participle adjective)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/449222/is-rumored-a-verb-or-an-adjective-a-participle-adjective) and compare 'Director George Lucas  was encouraged to create the Wookiee character Chewbacca ...'

Comment: It is passive voice of past indefinite tense; thus was + 3rd form of the verb.

Comment: I'm with JL on this. I think we have to say it's ambiguous between an active VP and the more likely 'short' passive VP ("inspired by someone*). Modification by "very" would disambiguate, as in "Lucas was _very inspired to create ..._", clearly an active VP.

Comment: You have to search a bit: https://www.bbc.com/culture/article/20150720-greatest-us-films-an-a-z-analysis

Answer (score 0):

"Inspired" is most likely a past participle here because **"inspired" describes the state of George Lucas** after seeing the dog.

It could also have been a verb in a sentence in the passive voice. However, if it were a verb, the structure, in my opinion, would be

> Director George Lucas was inspired to create the Wookiee character
> Chewbacca—a “gentle, hairy, non-English-speaking co-pilot"—**by (the act of)** seeing
> his wife’s dog sitting in the passenger seat of his car.

because, then, we could turn it into an active-voice sentence as follows.

> Seeing his wife’s dog sitting in the passenger seat of his car
> **inspired** Director George Lucas to create the Wookiee character
> Chewbacca—a “gentle, hairy, non-English-speaking co-pilot."

Because that is not the case, "inspired" is a past participle.

Answer (score -1):

Good question. However, there is one mistake in this sentence:

> Director George Lucas was inspired to create the Wookiee character Chewbacca – a “gentle, hairy, non-English-speaking co-pilot” – after ***having*** (not 'being') seen his wife’s dog sitting in the passenger seat of his car.

I am tempted to say that in this particular case it is a participle because it is followed by a to infinitive. In such structures you usually get *participle + to do something*. For example

> He is tempted to cheat, they are convinced to try

On the other hand you do get constructions with *adjective + to infinitive* as well:

> We are grateful to see you in good health.

But this could be rephrased as

> We are grateful for seeing you in good health.

So I would rather think we have a participle in your sentence. Hope this helps.

Comment: "Seeing" is better than "having seen". You might say that the perfect is redundant because the past/anterior meaning is conveyed by "after".

Comment: Yes, 'seeing' is definitely fine. 'after + present perfect' is not uncommon though, but it probably corresponds to my jolly care not make a mistake as a non-native speaker :)

Comment: @user405662: No. What makes you think that? :)

Comment: @user405662: My first answer was clear enough. I am not Italian.

Comment: I think your real question is 'From which country are you  from?' I think this is not relevant to the language question asked here, so let us not encumber the site with personal curiosities.

Comment: @fev Neither your country of origin nor your ethnicity is of any relevance to the question. However, as you say you are a non-native speaker, your native language is of relevance to the interpretation of your answer.

Comment: @BoldBen: I am Romanian, and you may be right, a Romance language speaker does tend to see language as mathematics. I was only apprehensive to irritate the administrators of the site with irrelevant conversations.

Comment: @user405662: I have no problem answering questions about language. I am not embarrassed, I just think that for _casual queries_ it is better to use a chat or something. I think the site provides that possibility.